# Storing alcohol in a thermos bottle

Tags: everyday-chemistry

My thermos bottle's instructions say:

> Füllen Sie keine kohlensäurehaltigen Flüssigkeiten oder Trockeneis in das Produkt. Füllen Sie keine alkoholischen oder öligen Flüssigkeiten in das Produkt.

This translates to:

> Do not fill carbonated liquids or dry ice into the product. Do not fill alcoholic or oily liquids into the product.

I suppose the reason you're not supposed to fill carbonated liquids or dry ice into the thermos bottle is that the bottle isn't able to handle the pressure which builds up if you close the lid. In the case of dry ice, it might also not be able to cope with the temperature of it. I further suppose that oil can wear down the seal.

But why are you not supposed to store alcohol in it? Sure, some alcoholic beverages are carbonated, but those already are excluded. What about beverages like mulled wine?

Comment: What makes you think you shouldn't store alcohol in it? Except for carbonated alcohols as you stated.

Comment: For all thermos I had alcohol wasn't a problem , I guess. Might some o-ring  get brittle/ harder upon prolonged alcoholic storage ?  I would say might be with very alcoholic drinks. Zum Voll :)

Comment: One issue is what material comprises the inner lining of the thermos. Typically, the inside of a thermos bottles are silvered glass. But that's not a guarantee and even if it is, there's no guarantee that there isn't a coating on the glass. The coating may degrade in the presence of alcohol. Also, oily substances are hard to clean out, and the manufacturer may not want people to think badly of their product because they couldn't clean it effectively.

Comment: Storing alcohol in copper is supposed to be a bad idea, because the oxide layer on the copper could oxidise ethanol. Not sure on what timescale that would happen. Stainless steel should be inert i think, and certainly glass is inert. There is no coating in a thermos, because that would certainly degrade when you fill in hot water.

Comment: At the temperature of dry ice, most common steel modifications become very brittle, the thermos would instantly break i think.

Comment: The only reason I have a thermos is to fill it with boozed tea...

Comment: As @Alchimista states, ethanol might attack the O-ring gasket... and also the plastic stopper. Another, less likely, reason is that at alcohol has a higher vapor-pressure than water, and at high temperatures that might burst the inner wall of the vacuum bottle.

Comment: Lower surface tension of alcoholic beverages could possibly allow excessive leakage. Leakage would/could also be a problem with carbonated beverages because of pressure buildup. Maybe the seal is not very snug (plastic rather than rubber). Maybe the thermos is just cheap junk.

Comment: @JamesGaidis My thermos is just cheap junk, I guess. If I leave anything hot in it, after an hour it always makes a high-pitched noise as air is trying to force its way in. If I take it anywhere in my backpack, I need to make sure it's standing upright or it'll leak.

Comment: The disclaimer was probably written by an attorney and may or may not have any physical chemical justification.